# Facebook API: Applying for the publish_stream Permission

Tags: facebook

Has anyone ever gotten a response from Facebook after you've applied for the "publish_stream" permission?  I've searched through their forum and found users with the same problem without an  answer.

[Facebook Developer: Using the Open Stream API](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Using_the_Open_Stream_API#Applying_for_the_publish_stream_Permission)

Comment: after 2 months of waiting, i finally received a confirmation email from Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for it today and I've found that the statement had disappeared from the Facebook developer wiki :

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php?title=Using_the_Open_Stream_API&diff=29336&oldid=28740

Could it be not required anymore ?